# Popup preview for Hyperlinks

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I don't know if there's any way to go about this but I've tried using `=IMAGE()` to show images of cells in a column that contain only hyperlinks of tracking numbers. I was hoping to make life easier for myself except this `=IMAGE()` makes the spreadsheet really cluttered. I was hoping to be able to similarly write something where you could roll your mouse over the hyperlink and have a temporary popup window show the hyperlink's contents; in this case, it would be the tracking number's contents shown. Is there any way to do this or is it impossible?

Answer (score 1):

Google Sheets / Google Apps Script don't have a mouse over event.

References

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events